# local.ERROR: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7700: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, curl, server, homestead

I'm currently trying to run an existing laravel project on homestead(virtualbox) and I keep running into this curl error when trying to log in/ register a user. I have set up the project manually (without homestead) on windows and end up getting the same error. The site otherwise seems to be working and can access the database to populate boxes on the home page so I would assume that connection to the db isn't the issue. I'm completely stuck for places to even look for issues and would really appreciate any suggestions.

stacktrace of the error:

```
[2021-09-25 16:41:45] local.ERROR: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7700: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1:7700/oauth/token {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7700: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1:7700/oauth/token at /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::createRejection()
#1 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finishError()
#2 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finish()
#3 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler->__invoke()
#4 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}()
#5 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}()
#6 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()
#7 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}()
#8 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(63): GuzzleHttp\\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke()
#9 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}()
#10 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(331): GuzzleHttp\\HandlerStack->__invoke()
#11 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(168): GuzzleHttp\\Client->transfer()
#12 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\\Client->requestAsync()
#13 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/ClientTrait.php(95): GuzzleHttp\\Client->request()
#14 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/app/Http/Controllers/Api/Auth/Traits/TokenManagement.php(80): GuzzleHttp\\Client->post()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/app/Http/Controllers/Api/Auth/Traits/TokenManagement.php(28): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Auth\\RegisterController->createToken()
#16 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/app/Http/Controllers/Api/Auth/RegisterController.php(36): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Auth\\RegisterController->loginUser()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Auth\\RegisterController->loginProvider()
#18 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(47): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#19 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(261): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#20 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(204): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#21 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#22 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#23 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#25 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#27 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#28 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#30 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#31 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#32 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#33 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#34 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#35 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#36 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#37 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#39 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#41 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#42 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#44 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#46 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#47 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#48 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#49 /home/vagrant/code/kiddiplan55/public/index.php(56): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#50 {main}


.env file:

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:5yJBmknlhoQTFZ2vvVUTpvQxv7u+RbZKMlwtXYvrfPE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD='secret'

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

LOG_CHANNEL=daily

DEFAULT_LAT_FOR_LOCATIONS=51.4623
DEFAULT_LON_FOR_LOCATIONS=0.1386

SCOUT_PREFIX=development_robert_
SCOUT_QUEUE=false


SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7700
MEILISEARCH_KEY=homestead
MEILISEARCH_LIMIT_PARENT=10000
MEILISEARCH_LIMIT_MERCHANTS=10000
BRAINTREE_ENV=sandbox
BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID=mp5cm5ttnfr26nmg
BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY=p99yv2sq7xfg8cy9
BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY=2cd25acc5c538de37e1b75821db0efe5
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_ONE_MONTH=01_MGBP
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_TWO_MONTHS=02_MGBP
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_THREE_MONTHS=03_MGBP
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_FOUR_MONTHS=04_MGBP
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_SIX_MONTHS=06_MGBP
BRAINTREE_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID_TWELVE_MONTHS=12_MGBP
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=dc88e5f106ccd21fb73e8179ad50db26-us12
MAILCHIMP_API_SERVER_NAME=us12
MAILCHIMP_KP_LIST_ID=ccd1c845cf
MAILCHIMP_KP_MERCHANTS_LIST_ID=46d8ab9fa7
MAILCHIMP_KP_NOT_IN_AREA_LIST_ID=ccd1c845cf

GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY=AIzaSyBpmWCjWGpcSTemM1MZ_Mty_f5yIgez57E

OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY=4b346f0b9f37d0ddad1ea3c4aa843ba1

LANDING_PAGE_CARDS=new

SENTRY_ENABLE=false

EMAIL_LOG_ACCESS_MIDDLEWARE=superadmin
EMAIL_LOG_ROUTES_PREFIX=email-logger/

PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:7700/oauth/token
PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID=2
PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET=123
PASSPORT_TOKEN_MINUTES=14440
PASSPORT_REFRESH_TOKEN_MINUTES=14440

DISABLE_ADVOCATE_PROMOTIONS=1
ADVOCATE_PROMOTIONS_AMOUNT=15.00
ADVOCATE_PROMOTION_MAX_USAGES=100

CRAFTY_CLICKS_KEY=bedeb-0b540-4c559-01aeb

CLEAR_TEMPORARY_ATTACHMENTS_AFTER_HOW_MANY_HOURS=48

USERS_TIMEZONE=Europe/London
```

Comment: Hi! 127.0.0.1:7700 is the address of a MeiliSearch instance, do you actually have one running?

Comment: Hi! Yes you're right I've checked and the Meilisearch is now running and I can access localhost:7700 however when I run the site in homestead the same thing happens. It also uses laravel passport which appears to be trying to access PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:7700/oauth/token (0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 because that was what it defaulted to when setting up meilisearch with docker). Would it be a passport issue or a meilisearch config issue?

Comment: Maybe you should try running meilisearch in a different port:  https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/configuration.html#http-address-port-binding

Answer (score 2):

So eventually I solved the issue and in case it helps anyone basically it was missing the correct setup for meilisearch and a `php artisan storage:link` command. The steps I took to solve the issue were:

On my virtual machine:

```
sudo su
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://apt.fury.io/meilisearch/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fury.list

apt update

apt install meilisearch-http=0.20.0 -V

meilisearch
```

Then in a seperate window but also ssh into the virtual machine code folder I ran:

```
php artisan storage:link

php artisan passport:install
```

Together these worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

are you 100% sure that port is open? Are you running it on the same server you are trying to connect to?

Try running the following code:

```
<?php
$hostIp = '127.0.0.1'; 
$hostPort = 7700; 
$timeoutTime = 1; 
if($fp = fsockopen($hostIp,$hostPort,$errCode,$errStr,$timeoutTime)){   
   echo 'Port is open';
} else {
   echo 'Port is closed';
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for helping this is killing me at my new job (it's old code the main dev has left the company) 

I put that code in and got the following:

ErrorException
fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:7700 (Connection refused)
http://homestead.test/